# Meteor Function vs Variable Tracking

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am learning meteor (and Javascript) and trying to understand a concept of why one thing works and not the other.

Inside my template I have

```
<template name="test">
    <p>Salary: {{salary}}</p>
    <button class="update">Update</button>
</template>
```

and in my client side .js I have the following:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Session.setDefault("salary", 100);

  Template.test.helpers({
    salary: function() {
      return Session.get("salary");
    }
  });

  Template.test.events({
    "click .update": function (event, template){
      Session.set("salary", Session.get("salary") + 100);
    }
  });
}
```

Which works how I expect it.

But it took quite a while to figure out that I need to set salary as a "function". As coming from a C# / WPF background I did the following:

```
  Template.test.helpers({
    salary: Session.get("salary")    
  });
```

Which caused automatic updates not to work and got me really scratching my head!

Why is it that for meteor.js you need to set a variable to a function in order for automatic updates to work? Is this a javascript limitation/thing or a meteor thing?

I tried  searching around, but have found nothing useful. I know how to get working, but trying to understand WHY I need to set the variable to a function rather than a value?

If someone could point me in the right direction I would be grateful!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When the code gets interpreted, the salary is evaluated to the right side of the expression, when that happens, `Session.get("salary")` gets evaluated on page load and that value is returned to the salary attribute.

When you set the value of salary to a function, salary value is attributed to a function, and that function gets called whenever you retrieve the salary value, thus running it again returns the current value of the `Session.get("salary")` statement.